# Prolog weighted undirected graph

Tags: prolog

Ik keep struggling with making a weighted undirected graph in Prolog.

The graph is represented by a x-number of predicates like:

```
% connection(+Source, +Destination, +Weight).
connection(A,B,2).
connection(A,C,3).
```

What i want to achieve is to make an predicate which gives me the route between two given points (like the route between point A and G)

The graph will be like this:

```
edge(A,B). 
edge(A,C). 
edge(B,D). 
edge(C,D). 
edge(D,F). 
edge(D,E). 
edge(B,F). 
edge(E,G).
```

The predicate has to be like this: `route(+From, +To, -Path)`

Any help is really appreciated!

*Edit

When I use this code:

```
path(Node, Node, _, [Node]).
path(Start, Finish, Visited, [Start | Path]) :-
    verbinding(Start, X,_),
    not(member(X, Visited)),
    path(X, Finish, [X | Visited], Path).
```

It gives me the result I want, but it is not following the predicate `route(+From, +To, -Path)`. I would like to get the route from point X to Y without having to worry about the weights.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your problem a bit more carefully. If you had a *directed*, *acyclic* graph, you could say:

```
path(To, To, [To]).
path(This, To, [This|Rest]) :-
    edge(This, Next),
    path(Next, To, Rest).
```

If your graph is *not acyclic*, you definitely need an extra argument.

```
path(From, To, Path) :-
    path_1(From, To, [], Path).
```

and your path_1 you sort of have already. You could re-write your check as

```
\+ memberchk(X, Visited)
```

but this is a detail. Also, don't leave spaces between the head, pipe symbol and tail in `[Head|Tail]`. The pipe in some implementations can be a synonym for the disjunction, `;`.

But: your graph is at the moment *directed*, it seems. If you want to make it an undirected graph, the easiest (it seems) would be to add each edge twice, once for each direction, say:

```
edge(a, b).
edge(b, a).
```

Or, maybe:

```
edge(A, B) :- connection(A, B).
edge(A, B) :- connection(B, A).
```

Then, you most certainly need the `Visited` context argument, as you do at the moment.

This answer so far completely ignores weights.

Comment: My problem better explained: I need a predicate route(+From, +To, -Path) wich gives me a sequence of nodes. So that: route(a,g) gives the answer: route = [a,b,e,g]

Comment: @Marino1993 If you can, get "The Craft of Prolog" by Richard O'Keefe. It has a very thorough chapter on searching which will probably give you all the answers you need.

Comment: Thats indeed what i meant :)

Comment: edge(1,2).
edge(1,3).
edge(2,4).
edge(3,4).
edge(4,6).
edge(4,5).
edge(2,6).
edge(5,7).

Comment: @Marino1993 This should be in the question, not here

Comment: @Marino1993 I still don't understand what it the problem with the solution you have at the moment?